# Combining masking and dense layers for non-sequential data in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I'm working on a classification problem where I have data of different lengths. Each sample is a numpy array of real values between -1 and 1. Because each sample is of different length I am using padding so I can feed it to a neural network. According to tensorflow's documentation, I also need a masking layer in conjunction with padding. However I have also read that not every layer will propagate the mask, and I am concerned that this could be the reason my network underperforms. I have ran the classifier with and without the padding + masking layers and the results are similar. I would like to ask you what is the best way to use a masking layer in conjunction with dense layers. Below is a sample of the code for my network.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Masking
from tensorflow.keras.utils import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_padded = pad_sequences(X, padding='post', dtype='float32')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_padded, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=101, shuffle=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train, epochs=600, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Training data looks more or less like this:

```
X = [[-0.1, 0.2, 0.1], [0.4, 0.3], [-0.2, -0.44, 0.32, 0.5], ...]
y = [0, 1, 1, ...]
```